# My div only reaches half the page even on 100% height

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have this page [here](http://bocado.launchlabs.asia/?page_id=680) and the div `.menu-content` only reaches half the page even on 100% height. I really have no idea why.

Thanks!

```
<div class = "menu-content">
<div class="wrapper" style = "background-color:white; height:100%; width:750px;">
 <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <?php the_content(); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else : ?>
 <?php global $rd_data; if ($rd_data['rd_error_text']) { ?>
  <?php echo $rd_data['rd_error_text']; ?>
  <?php } else { ?>
  Oops, It looks like an error has occured
  <?php } ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: In which where is the menu-content ?

Comment: You could view the page and Inspect Element, If you're asking for a code.

Comment: are u talking about menu or pop-up on that page/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `height:100%;` on `.menu-content .wrapper` in your CSS code and in the inline style you set on it.

That way it will be set to default `height:auto;` and the height will be calculated by it's content.

Comment: That Worked! I kinda forgot that I placed a 100% height on wrapper on the php file. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try this css..

```
.menu-content {
    display: table;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use css this way. use the `overflow:auto` property and remove the unnecessary  property like `z-index` and `position` from class `.wrapper`.

```
.menu-content {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 750px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `html {height: 100%}` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

to solve this you can simply add  a div with `style = "clear:both;"` at the end of your   div `.menu-content`

like this :

```
<div class="menu-content">
.....................
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```